# What is the shortcut key for Run to cursor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, shortcut

What is the shortcut key for *Run to cursor* in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The shortcut key is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 17):

The default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> but it can be overridden.  The place to find what your current shortcuts are and change them is

> **T**ools
>   **C**ustomize...
>   **K**eyboard...
>   Show **c**ommands containing:
>   Debug.RunToCursor

or

> **T**ools
>   **O**ptions
>   **E**nvironment
>   **K**eyboard
>   Show **c**ommands containing:
>   Debug.RunToCursor

Answer (score 2):

While on debug mode click on '**Run**' you will see '**Run to Line**' there in-front of it there will be a short key give which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can first hit

```
Ctrl + Shift + P
```

Then type "`> Run to Cursor`"

if you click on "gear" icon on the right, you can double click and set the shortcut at your convenience.

Also you can c/p: `@command:editor.debug.action.runToCursor`

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2008, not Visual Studio Code.